# Angular Js File Upload For Image,Video,audio with preview

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

In my project i have a form with upload options three type of upload is available when user click on image button `.image` upload has to triggered and like other two other section has to show. I am showing it using `ng-if` condition. If the condition is not added the functionalities are working fine. If condition is added it throws an exception.

HTML FILES:

```
<body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="mediaController">
<div class="formWrapper">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="UploadFunction('image');">Image</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="UploadFunction('audio')">Audio</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="UploadFunction('video')">Video</button>
    <form name="mediaForm" novalidate>
        <fieldset>  
            <div class="row1">  
                <div class="inpWrapper">
                    <input type="text" name="mediaName" ng-model="mediaValues.mediaName" class="form-control" required ng-class="{'submitted': submitted}" placeholder="Media Name">
                    <div ng-messages='mediaForm.mediaName.$error' ng-if='submitted && mediaForm.mediaName.$invalid'>
                        <div ng-message='required' class="has-error">Please enter the media Name</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="inpWrapper">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="mediaValues.mediaDesc" name="mediaDesc" class="form-control" required ng-class="{'submitted': submitted}" placeholder="Media Description" />
                    <div ng-messages='mediaForm.mediaDesc.$error' ng-if='submitted && mediaForm.mediaDesc.$invalid'>
                        <div ng-message='required' class="has-error">Please enter the media Description</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="inpWrapper" ng-show="mediaValues.fileupload == 'image'">
                     <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="file" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required ngf-model-invalid="errorFile">
                    <div ng-show="mediaForm.file.$error.maxSize">File too large max 2M</div>                 
                    <img ng-show="myForm.file.$valid" ngf-thumbnail="picFile" class="thumb"/>
                        <button ng-click="picFile = ''" ng-show="picFile">Remove</button>        
                        <div class="progress" ng-show="picFile.progress >= 0">
                            <div style="width:{{picFile.progress}}%;" class="progress-bar">{{picFile.progress}}%</div>
                        </div>
                        <span ng-show="picFile.result">Upload Successful</span>
                        <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="inpWrapper" ng-show="mediaValues.fileupload == 'audio'">
                    <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile1" name="file" accept="audio/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required ngf-model-invalid="errorFile">
                    <div ng-show="mediaForm.file.$error.maxSize">File too large max 2M</div>                 
                    <audio controls ng-show="mediaForm.file.$valid" ngf-src="picFile1" ngf-accept="audio/*" ></audio>
                        <button ng-click="picFile1 = ''" ng-show="picFile1">Remove</button>      
                        <div class="progress" ng-show="picFile1.progress >= 0">
                            <div style="width:{{picFile1.progress}}%;" class="progress-bar">{{picFile1.progress}}%</div>
                        </div>
                        <span ng-show="picFile1.result">Upload Successful</span>
                        <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="inpWrapper" ng-if="mediaValues.fileupload == 'video'">
                    <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="file" accept="video/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required ngf-model-invalid="errorFile">
                    <div ng-show="mediaForm.file.$error.maxSize">File too large max 2M</div>                 
                    <video controls ng-show="mediaForm.file.$valid" ngf-src="picFile" ngf-accept="video/*" ></video>
                        <button ng-click="picFile = ''" ng-show="picFile">Remove</button>        
                        <div class="progress" ng-show="picFile.progress >= 0">
                            <div style="width:{{picFile.progress}}%;" class="progress-bar">{{picFile.progress}}%</div>
                        </div>
                        <span ng-show="picFile.result">Upload Successful</span>
                        <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="inpWrapper">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                            <button class="success transparentBtn" ng-disabled="!mediaForm.$valid"  ng-click="uploadPic(picFile)">Save</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                            <input type="button" class="cancel transparentBtn" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="reset();" value="Cancel"/>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </fieldset> 
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

JS FILES:

```
//inject angular file upload directives and services.
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('mediaController', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
$scope.mediaValues = {};
var defaultObj = $scope.mediaValues;
$scope.mediaValues.fileupload = 'image';    
$scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
    $scope.submitted =  true;
    var formName = $scope.mediaValues.mediaName;
    var desc = $scope.mediaValues.mediaName;
    if($scope.submitted && $scope.mediaForm.$valid ){
        file.upload = Upload.upload({
            url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            method: 'POST',
          data: {username: formName, file: file}
        });

        file.upload.then(function (response) {
          $timeout(function () {
            file.result = response.data;
          });
        }, function (response) {
          if (response.status > 0)
            $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
        }, function (evt) {
          // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
          file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
        });
    }           
}
$scope.UploadFunction = function(value){
    $scope.mediaValues.fileupload = value;      
    alert($scope.mediaValues.fileupload);
};
$scope.reset = function(picFile){
    var uploadType = $scope.mediaValues.fileupload;
    /*alert(uploadType);
    if(uploadType == 'image')
        $scope.picFile = null;
    else
        $scope.picFile == '';*/
    $scope.mediaValues = angular.copy(defaultObj);
    $scope.submitted =  false;
    $scope.mediaForm.$setPristine();
}
}]);
```

Comment: what exception?

Comment: its not reading the upload file name.

Comment: On the server side? Can you elaborate more on the specifics of the error maybe a jsfiddle or screenshot.